# How do I call a module function in Powershell Start-job

Tags: powershell

I try to send a module's method/function to a job.
How do I execute the method/function inside the job?

---

```
# Create a module with 1 method.
$m = New-Module -ScriptBlock{
        function start(){
            "started"
        };
    } -AsCustomObject

# Start a job and send in the function/method.
Start-Job -ScriptBlock{
    $func = $args[0]
    "<args0:$func>" # The function/method seems to contain what I want.
    $func # <------------ How do I call $func/$m.start?
} -ArgumentList $m.start
```

Running the above and then `job 498 | Receive-Job -Keep` gives:

```
PS C:\temp\> job 500 | Receive-Job -Keep
<argsO:System.Object start();>

RunspaceId          : 9271e389-cc97-4d2a-9396-5f0ce3f0ae5c
Script              : 
                                      "started"

OverloadDefinitions : {System.Object start();}
MemberType          : ScriptMethod
TypeNameOfValue     : System.Object
Value               : System.Object start();
Name                : start
IsInstance          : True
```

so to all my knowledge I do have the function/method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting the question I found:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock{
    $func = $args[0]
    "<args0:$func>" # The function/method seems to contain what I want.
    $script = [scriptblock]::Create($func.Script);
    $script.Invoke()
} -ArgumentList $m.start
```

But as my colleague said: *Hmmm who is supposed to understand this?*
Isn't there any less convoluted way to run a method?

Answer (score 0):

start is a scriptmethod. You need to call start as method.

```
$M | Get-Member
$M.start()

# Create a module with 1 method.
$m = New-Module -ScriptBlock{
        function start(){
            mkdir 'C:\Vincent\job'
        };
    } -AsCustomObject

# Start a job and send in the function/method.
Start-Job -ScriptBlock{
    $func = $args[0]
    "<args0:$func>" # The function/method seems to contain what I want.
    $func # <------------ How do I call $func/$m.start?
} -ArgumentList $m.start()
```

[Importing Modules using -AsCustomObject](https://powershellstation.com/2012/02/08/importing-modules-using-ascustomobject/)

Comment: In your example $m.start() is executed when the job is started, isn't it? - not inside the job. Say that my `"<args0:$func>"` did something relevant and that I had to call `$func()` _after_ `"<args0:$func>"`.